# Stripe Creating Direct Charges to connect account

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I am trying to use stripe Direct Charges and it's working when user user new card (with token id).

Problem: When trying with save customer id and save card id. When i am trying to charge with custom-id and source=> save card id It's giving error customer not exist. But Both customer and card id exist.

```
$charge = \Stripe\Charge::create([
                                "customer" => $userdata->stripe_id,
                                  "amount" => $amount,
                                  "currency" => "usd",
                                  "source" => $findcard['card_id'],
                                  "application_fee" => $fee,
                                ], ["stripe_account" => $talent_stripeid]);
```

Error: No such customer: cus_EOwmc6nVmU7oNu

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error and when reached out to Stripe support got the following answer which helped me to solve the issue:

> The error you are running into is happening because the customer
>   object is on the platform account, but when you add the
>   "Stripe-account" parameter to your charge request, you're moving the
>   command to the connected account, and so can't reach the customer
>   object.
>
> To make the customer available, you'll need to share the customer to
>   the connected account. You'll basically create a token or source from
>   the customer object on your platform, and then share that with the
>   connected account, to process a payment, or to save locally, so the
>   connected account can use it directly.
>
> https://stripe.com/docs/connect/shared-customers
>
> Alternatively, you can keep the customer information on your platform
>   account and perform Destination charges, just sending to the connected
>   account "their share" of the proceeds:
>
> https://stripe.com/docs/connect/destination-charges